# Angular: Recorrer arreglo con ForEach

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
bookingModel: {
    afiliado: {
      attentionSchedule: [
        place: {
          "_id": "xxx"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Y yo quiero recorrer este objeto para llegar al array con un foreach, y asi poder obtener al string "_id", probé haciendolo de la siguiente manera:

```
lugar:any = [];
this.lugar = this.bookingModel?.affiliate?.attentionSchedules.forEach((place, index: any) => {
        return place.place._id;
      })
      console.log('lugarrrr', this.lugar);
```

Pero recibo this.lugar como undefined ¿porqué sucede esto? ¿cual es la mejor manera de acceder a la propiedad de un array que esta dentro de un objeto?

Comment: Si ese código te funciona, el objeto no tiene la estructura que has puesto en la pregunta

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, @PabloLozano ya lo corregí editando la pregunta, mala mía, Ahora bien ¿cómo debería de hacerlo en ese sentido?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes algunas diferencias en el modelo que presentas y las propiedades a las que quieres acceder. Omitiendo estos problemas (supongo que son más por transcribir) el problema en general es que `forEach` no devuelve un valor. Para eso necesitas [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let bookingModel = {
  afiliado: {
    attentionSchedule: [{
      place: {
        "_id": "xxx"
      }
    }]
  }
}

let lugar = [];
lugar = bookingModel.afiliado .attentionSchedule.map(attentionSchedule => {
  return attentionSchedule.place._id;
})
console.log('lugarrrr', lugar);
```